# DisplayFormat with CultureInfo DateTime

Tags: c#, localization, data-annotations

I'm trying to get set the DisplayFormat of a public property to the current cultureinfo datetime format. The class will be used for Silverlight Datagrid.

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString=CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToString())]
    public DateTime createDate { get; set; }
```

It says, only that the argument can only be constant and typeof parameter...

Any ideas?

UPDATE, I tried Lukazoid solution but the Silverlight datagrid ignores the data annotations. The datagrid colums are added in codebehind because of localization.

The column looks like this:

```
        DataGridTextColumn tcCreateDate = new DataGridTextColumn();
        tcCreateDate.Header = SilverlightApplication.Resources.ContentGrid.dgCreateDate;
        tcCreateDate.Binding = new Binding("createDate");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attribute values must be constant or a result of the `typeof` syntax.

If you want to use the short date format for the current culture, use the following format string:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
```

**Update**

I can see your updated code to add the `DataGridTextColumn`, try this to add the `StringFormat`:

```
DataGridTextColumn tcCreateDate = new DataGridTextColumn();
tcCreateDate.Header = SilverlightApplication.Resources.ContentGrid.dgCreateDate;
tcCreateDate.Binding = new Binding("createDate") { StringFormat = "{0:d}" };
```

By default, silverlight uses en-US as the current culture for all bindings (regardless of your system settings), this means the `StringFormat` will result in a US format of the date. See [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx) for a solution to ensure your current settings are taken into account.

Comment: Well it doesn't work as I thought. I'm using the class within a datagrid on silverlight. Do I have to set the display format for the datagrid column too?

Comment: It appears the silverlight datagrid ignores this attribute, so I would use the format string in the datagrid column (I also feel it's preferential to have the UI formatting in the UI instead of hidden in the code)

Comment: For Localization, I'm adding the datagrid columns in codebehind instead of the xaml. Do you know, how to add this string? See my updated post.

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if this does what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Now I'm getting a date format 07/20/2012. But the current culture is German, where we have the format 20.07.2012.

Comment: I've got a feeling that is an issue with silverlight applying en-US to all bindings (it's the same in WPF). See [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx) for a solution.

Comment: Yes, you where right. Thanks for this Link. Could you update your post, so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Tried like this

```
public class Foo
{
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime createDate { get; set; }
}
```

This will display with the date base culture of your project